# Implementing multiple combo boxes results in only one drop down button

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

Using the code here :http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox
But replacing id with a class results in almost the desired functionality... except there is only drop down button for all combox box's. How to get a drop down button for each combobox ?

```
<div class="ui-widget" style="display: inline-block;" >
  <select id="tag01" class="comboBox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
      <c:forEach items="${allTags}" var="tag">
        <option value="${tag.title}">${tag.title}</option>
      </c:forEach>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget" style="display: inline-block;" >
  <select id="tag02" class="comboBox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <c:forEach items="${allTags}" var="tag">
      <option value="${tag.title}">${tag.title}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
</div>
```

and then calling comboxbox like so :

```
 $("#tag01").combobox();
 $("#tag02").combobox();
```

or

```
 $(".comboBox").combobox();
```

results in only one drop down button. Only if I remove display inline block from style of divs do I get multiple buttons, but then the combox boxs are on multiple lines - I do not want this.

Comment: can you give demo in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @KarSho cannot import jquery-ui

Comment: at-least just post some code of you.

Comment: are you use correct css and widget function ? and check the spelling '.combox'....

Comment: sorry, i don't know where you mistook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down button is absolutely positioned,  which means it does not impact the normal flow of the page. When you add the second combo box, the combination with `position: relative` in the container element leads to a box stacked on top of the button. Leaving some space on the right of the `.ui-widget` elements solves the problem.

For example,

```
<div class="ui-widget" style="display: inline-block; margin-right:40px">
  <select id="tag01" class="comboBox">
    ...
   </select>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/YH3ep/3/ for a demo